# How can I prove that the plaintext of an elgamal ciphertext is the discrete log of an element?

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, discrete-logarithm, elgamal-encryption

Is there any (efficient) method to prove that the plaintext of an ElGamal ciphertext is the discrete log of an element?

In the scenario I concerned, I have an El Gamal key pair $(pk, sk) = (g^y, y)$. How can I prove that $m$ in the ciphertext $c = (g^x, mg^{yx})$ is the discrete log of $g^m$ (could be other bases like $h$, $h^m$) to other people who only have $pk$ without revealing m (i.e., in zero-knowledge proof of knowledge)?

Note that other people (verifier) already have the element $c = (g^x, mg^{yx})$ and $g^m$ (or $h$ and $h^m$).

Comment: will post a longer answer if I get time, but briefly: for Elgamal over a standard prime order group, this does not make sense. Assume for simplicity that the base group is the group of squares mod a safe prime p. Because exponents and base elements do not have the same order, for any m and g^n, I can find some integer x such that x=m mod p, and x=n mod p-1 (the order of the group of exponents). Therefore  the statement is trivial, unless you somehow manage to prove that you know a *short* such x.

Comment: Do you mean to prove that $m$ is in the subgroup generated by $g$?  Or, do you mean to prove that you know the value of $m$ (and not only that it exists)?  Or, do you really mean to imply that $m = g^m$ (that is, you don't accidentally use $m$ for two different meanings in your question)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @GeoffroyCouteau and sorry for my unclear question. I just edit the question and I manage to prove that I know such $m$ in this question.

Comment: @poncho thank you very much for your comment and sorry for my unclear question. I just edit the question. In this question, I hope that I can prove that I know the value of $m$, such that it is the plaintext of a given elgamal ciphertext and also the discrete log of an given element (the base could be another one instead of $g$, but should be given).

Comment: Still, my comment applies: in general, this statement does not make sense, syntactically. That is, the exponents in $g^x$ do  not live in the same group as the group elements themselves, and even not in a group of the same order. In this case, it *cannot* make sense to talk about $m$ being the same value as a group element (ElGamal plaintext) and exponent: for *any* pair $(m, g^{m'})$, I can find some large enough integer $x$, using the CRT, such that $m = x$ (in the group) and $g^{m'} = g^x$. Hence the statement becomes trivial.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau thank you very much for your kind reply. How about the case in which the ciphertext is the same as the case I mentioned, but we use $h^m$ instead of $g^m$, where $h$ is already given and has the order $p$?

Comment: Do you mean that $h$ generates a different group, such that the group of exponents of $h$ is isomorphic to the base group of ElGamal? In this case yes, the question can make sense.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau Yes, that is the case I consider.